# Bootstrap 4 .nav-item and .nav-link classes

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-identity

The HTML code created by the ASP.NET Identity scaffolder contains HTML code like this (much simplified) in _ManageNav.cshtml:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="active"><a href="/something">Profile</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/something-else">Password</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that this HTML does not contain any reference to either the `.nav-item` or `.nav-link` class, as described in the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#pills). Moreover, a search of the project files (in particular, the Bootstrap source code included with the project) doesn't turn up any evidence that these classes even exist.

What this all about?  I can't find anything obvious with The Google that says that these classes are gone, but the scaffolded code obviously works properly without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the scaffolding is still based on `bootstrap 3`? Although bootstrap 4 documentation doesn't state it, `nav-stacked` class is gone for `bootstrap4` as the `<nav>` now is based on `flex-box`.

To make vertical navs, you use `flex-column` now: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#vertical

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The bootstrap.css file included with the project (wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css) file states that it is `Bootstrap v3.3.7`